# How to create Listview in Java [Swing]?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jlist

How to display a simple ListView in Java? Could you please give me a simple sample code on how to create ListView?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you mean [JList](http://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=JList&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html&ei=exAiT8zzAtHQsgaN6OnJDg&usg=AFQjCNHF2QzUAhmLWN7mxTNHeggj4Kx-Lw&sig2=s0W7wJlH-RljBZb58xXKLw)?, see java tutorials: [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [Java swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/overview/demo.html) and [ListView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/ListView.html) API reference - Its an implementation of `<html>` list - `<ol><li>`.

Sample :

```
public class Sample extends JFrame   {
    public Sample(){
        JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
        pane.setContentType("text/html");
        pane.setText("<ol id='foo'><li>One</li><li>Two</li></ol>"); 
        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) pane.getDocument();
        add(pane);

        //Get the ref of foo element
        Element ele=doc.getElement("foo");
        ListView view=new ListView(ele);
        System.out.println(ele.getElementCount());
        try{
             doc.insertBeforeEnd(ele.getElement(0), "<ul><li>Test");          
        }catch(Exception ex){}
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was surprised I had not given that an up-vote when I first saw it! I suspect I got too preoccupied with following the link to discover exactly what a `ListView` was. ;)  Corrected now. :)

Comment: If you could change one aspect of your answer, I could delete my inferior answer.  The change:  *"..list - `<ol><li>`."* to something like.. *"..list - the `<li>` elements of an `<ol>` or `<ul>`."*.   The most important part being **or `<ul>`**.  Let me know what you decide.

Answer (score 4):

According tho the JavaDocs it is used when rendering HTML, so using it is is just a matter of loading some HTML that uses an HTML list (`<ul>` or `<ol>`).

[image: Show HTML List]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ShowHtmlList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // invoke HTML renderring in HTML aware components
        sb.append("<html>");
        // start (the body &) an ordered list
        sb.append("<body><ol>");
        Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.
            getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
        for (Font font : fonts) {
            String name = font.getName();
            // will be rendered using a *** ListView ***
            sb.append("<li style='font-family: " + 
                name + "; font-size: 20px;'>");
            sb.append(name);
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(
                    new JLabel(sb.toString()));
                Dimension d = sp.getPreferredSize();
                sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width, 150));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sp);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

OTOH it might be the data is better presented in a `JList` as suggested in a number of other replies.